# Android keep CountDown Service going after exiting

Tags: java, android, service, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer service that I start when my mainActivity's onCreate() method is called upon. The trouble is, that once I leave the application, that service stops. I've looked at a lot of tutorials on [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ9-6V467RAhUQS2MKHQgFB7UQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F32028134%2Fhow-to-keep-a-countdowntimer-running-even-if-the-app-is-closed&usg=AFQjCNE4Ms9VSq_TTR4S_rN-8PnDugQGLQ&sig2=PjjmmwM8NZGnQ-8uZ9Etfg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.cGc) but I still get the service getting stopped. Here's what I got, what can I do to keep the service on going even after I quit the app?

mainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    //create new notifications based from settings
    ni = new NotifyTimeInterface(this.getApplicationContext());

    setTimes();

    //register a receiver to update the "next notify text"
    registerReceiver(bcsr, new IntentFilter("update_next_text"));

    //start the notifications/adhan service, pass the prayer times
    countdownServiceIntent.putExtra("timingsArray", timings);
    startService(countdownServiceIntent);

}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();


    //should we get back from settings, redraw the main screen 
    this.onCreate(null);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    //if I do not stop the service I get a service leak
    stopService(countdownServiceIntent);
    unregisterReceiver(bcsr);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In the CountDownService:

```
public class CountDownService extends Service
{
  CountDownTime ctx;
  Date n1;
  Date n2;
  Date n3;
  Date n4;
  Date n5;
  Date nNext;

  Intent soundServiceIntent;

  Date[] times = null;
  Intent nextTextIntent;
public CountDownService()
{

}
public void setTimes(Date f, Date d, Date a, Date m, Date i)
{
    //set the times passed in from main to here
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i)
{
    try
    {
        times = (Date[]) i.getSerializableExtra("timingsArray");
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    setTimes(times[0], times[1], times[2], times[3], times[4]);
}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    soundServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SoundService.class);

    onHandleIntent(intent);
    getNextTime();
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
public void startTicking()
{
    Date nowDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    long difference = 0;
    if(nextPrayerTime != null)
    {
        difference = nextNotifyTime.getTime() - nowDate.getTime();
    }
    if(difference > 0)
    {
        ctx = new CountDownTime(difference, 1000);
        ctx.start();
    }
}
public void getNextTime()
{
    //next notification time is set here...
    //afterwards, start the timer
    startTicking();
}
private void addNotification() 
{
      NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
         (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mini_icon)
     .setContentTitle("Notification!")
     .setContentText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());

      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

      // Add as notification
      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      manager.notify(0, builder.build());
      return;
}
public class CountDownTime extends CountDownTimer
{

    public CountDownTime(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        String textString = ("Next notify in: " + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
                ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60), ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60)));
        nextTextIntent = new Intent("update_next_text");
        nextTextIntent.putExtra("countdownTime", textString);
        sendBroadcast(nextTextIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        startService(soundServiceIntent);
        addNotification();
        getNextTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: your service stops when leaving the app .... you have `stopService(countdownServiceIntent);` in `onDestroy()` - it will stop, you've told it to! `//if I do not stop the service I get a service leak` - why its not a bound connection? Post the leak Stacktrace.